# Spring Ibatis : Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for

Tags: spring, ibatis

I have a mapper. Using that mapper's insert function, I am able to insert the records successfully. But while using `deleteByPrimaryKey` it throwing the error

```
Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for
```

My mapper file is in the correct location and namespaces are also correct.

When I'm able to insert successfully, why it is failing to delete?

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Mapped-Statements-collection-does-not-contain-value-td2553948.html

> The three names have to match: 
>    - interface = com.enlliance.inventory.mappers.SettingMapper.class 
>    - mapper file = /com/enlliance/inventory/mappers/SettingMapper.xml 
>    - mapper namespace = com.enlliance.inventory.mappers.SettingMapper 
>   If they don't match, it won't work.